# Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid auth credential

Tags: node.js, google-secret-manager

My Node.js code utilizing Google Secret Manager stopped working (it worked fine some time ago). I have set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable to valid path and `console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)`; prints it correctly.
I've even tried to re-generate new .json file and still get the same error. Originally it was without keyFilename, but both give same results, the error. The keys are enabled in the management website.
I have tried to call `await client.initialize();` as well.

Is there a way to debug this more? Could a recent change from winter to summer time have effect? But then why re-generated keys don't work?

```
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient({
  keyFilename: 'path-to.json'
});

const projectId = 'project-number';
const parent = 'projects/' + projectId;

...
async function listSecrets() { // Calling this throws the error
  const [secrets] = await client.listSecrets({
    parent: parent
  });
```

Full error stack:

```
[2021-04-12T09:14:56.366Z] (node:51988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (<super-secret-path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (<super-secret-path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:176:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (<super-secret-path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:336:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (<super-secret-path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at <super-secret-path>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:130:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Comment: Where is this code running?

Comment: On Node.js server

Comment: My own server, not in Google Cloud, if that was the point of the question :-)

Comment: Can you share the full error message please?

Comment: I've edited the question and added full message :)

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Are you sure you have a valid service account key file?

Comment: I have the old one, that worked before (3.4.0 version of the @google-cloud/secret-manager), I've updated to 3.6.0 (but also many other dependencies in my project) it didn't work, I've generated new file and it still didn't work. Downgrade to 3.4.0 also doesn't work anymore... Is there a way to make the app say which credentials it's going to use? Or get anything useful from what .initialize() returns?

Comment: Removing the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable and path doesn't have any effect, error is still the same.
I wonder if it's taking the credentials from somewhere else...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've installed Google Cloud SDK, ran `gcloud auth activate-service-account` on my server, it fired

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.', '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim."}')
```

Which, after further Googling, led me to check my server's time, which was 2h behind now, due to recent change winter->summer, I suppose before it was 1h late which still fit.
**Adjusting the time solved the problem.** (http://time.is is helpful)

Funnily enough, I could login with "human" credentials.

Comment: It just solved my problem as well. My system clock was 2 hrs behind and was giving the same error. Thank you for sharing the solution

Comment: Unbelievable. This was my problem as well (I was using OSX-KVM as a host for functions development and the VM had not updated its own time after a host machine suspend/resume cycle). Of course the tokens are time sensitive...

Comment: spent about five hours stuck on this... checked the time on my laptop and the date was off by a day... reset it and now it works.

Comment: This worked in my case too. The event listener was working properly on my local computer. It was throwing an error of authentication on the server. I checked the timezone and the current time on the server and got to know it was off by 5 hours as per the selected timezone. I updated the time and the event listener started working immediately.  Thank you for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is encountered using firebase in the backend , try and set your Operating system to automatic :)

Comment: try and set  your Operating system time to automatic :)

Comment: I was using Node.js in the backend

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).